# HTML CSS and Tailwind css when class is contains absolute in navbar, cursor pointer is not working, when i remove absolute cursor pointer is working

Tags: html, css, web, tailwind-css

```
<nav class="flex justify-between absolute items-center w-full p-40px">
      <div class="left flex items-center cursor-pointer">
        <span class="text-white"
          ><i class="w-29px mb-5px border-2 border-t-white rotate-12 block"></i
          ><i class="w-29px mb-5px border-2 border-t-white rotate-12 block"></i
          ><i class="w-29px mb-5px border-2 border-t-white rotate-12 block"></i>
        </span>
        <p class="ml-20px font-semibold text-white">Menu</p>
      </div>

      <div class="center cursor-pointer">
        <a href="#">
          <img
            src="https://www.kaft.com/resources-2.00.040/images/kaft_logo.svg"
            alt=""
          />
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="right"></div>
    </nav>
    <section class="first h-screen relative">
      <img
        src="https://www.kaft.com/static/images/content/banner/655.jpg?1696931601000"
        alt=""
        class="h-full w-full object-cover hero-img absolute"
      />
      <div
        class="text text-gray h-full w-full flex flex-col justify-end items-end p-100px font-rumeur"
      >
        <p class="text-xl">Ruga</p>
        <h1 class="text-6xl mt-10px">2 New Colors</h1>
      </div>
    </section>
```

in my "left" class cursor pointer is not working. when i remove absolute class in navbar, cursor pointer is working. please help me for solve this.

i tried remove absolute class and fixed but i dont want this.